# PHP csv parser eating characters like "é", "í", at the start of a field

Tags: php, regex, csv, fgetcsv

I am trying to parse a csv file in PHP. My problem is the following: If there is a field stating with "é" or "í", the parser eats all those characters from the start of a field.

The problem is only present on my host, it's not present when using XAAMP locally (newer PHP version). The PHP version on my host with the bug is: 5.2.6-1+lenny9

The code is nothing but one line of fgetcsv.

```
while (($program = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {...}
```

This code already outputs the "eaten" version, for example when viewed by print_r.

Is there anything I can do? It must be a bug in PHP something, which has been fixed since then. One alternative option I found out was to just escape the sequence, by putting a comma at the end of a field (my csv source, Google Spreadsheets automatically wraps the field in " " if there is a , present inside). Then I can write a function that deletes the last character if it's a comma (any help on this?).

Is is (or was it) a known bug in PHP, and were there any solutions for this? If not, can you help me with the delete-last-character-if-its-a-comma function?

Comment: You can use `print PHP_VERSION;` to find out. And there are alternative implementations in the [`fgetcsv` manual page](http://php.net/fgetcsv) which you could try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, its: 5.2.6-1+lenny9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual problem is that the webserver runs under a locale which forbids multibyte charsets. If set to `C` I get the same result:

```
<?php print_r(str_getcsv("ée, íi, zz, bb, "));

$   LC_ALL=C   php test_getcsv.php
```

Cuts of the `é` and `í` in fields.  `[0] => e
    [1] => i
    [2] => zz`

But when I run it like this:

```
$   LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8  php test_getcsv.php
```

I get the correct results. `[0] => ée
    [1] => íi
    [2] => zz`

You will need to investigate which locales are available on your server, then use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "xy_zz.UTF-8")` at the start of your script.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've put 'setlocale(LC_ALL, "hu.UTF-8");' at the start of the function, but no difference. It's a Hungarian host so it must be supported. If there is no error produced, does it mean that setlocale is accepted? I tried hu_HU.UTF-8 but no difference. Is there any way to print if a local was accepted or not?

Comment: @zsero: If it doesn't work, then it's most likely not supported. You can `print` the return string of `setlocale()` to see if it was accepted. It's empty for `print setlocale("KLINGON.UCS-4")` for example.

Comment: I am actually trying to find out which locales are supported. What I'm doing is `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'hu_HU');
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
echo(strftime('%Y. %B %d. %A'));` But it still stays Hungarian. If I put "C", it changes. Is it possible that no UTF-8 locale is supported on that host?

Comment: You can use `print system("locale -a")` to find out which are installed. It's surpringly often that you can use `en_GB.UTF-8` but not `en_US`

Comment: Thank you for all your help, but it seems that no UTF8 locale is supported on that very host. On all other hosts I tried, the following file produced different lines after hu_HU, but on that host, it doesnt. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
echo(strftime('%Y. %B %d. %A<br>'));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "hu_HU");
echo(strftime('%Y. %B %d. %A<br>'));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
echo(strftime('%Y. %B %d. %A<br>'));
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.utf8");
echo(strftime('%Y. %B %d. %A<br>'));` I think there is nothing left what I can do with that host, i'll just do the dirty remove comma trick.